# LINQ table join with entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my database I have ... TableA, TableB and TableC

TableB has just 2 columns, the primary key of TableA and TableC, so it really defines a one to many relationship between the two tables

What I want to do using SQL is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TablesA a
JOIN TablesB b ON a.AID = b.AID
WHERE b.BID = 1
```

In the Entity Framework it doesn't create a TablesB for me to do the join, I think because TableB only has foreign keys!

So how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables

Answer (score 8):

Doing a join with LINQ is fairly straightforward

```
from a in TablesA
join b in TablesB
on a.AID equals b.AID
into joined
where b.BID == 1
select joined
```

I think the real question may be - why don't you have an entity class for `TablesB`? We may need more information to answer that.

Comment: I think it's because TableB is made up of foreign keys so therefor it doesn't get shown!

Answer (score 3):

When you import the tables from database, entity framework gets rid of the TableB table and shows TableA and TableC to have many to many relationships. TableA  has a navigation property TableCs and vice versa. So all you need to use these navigation properties, for sample:

```
var tableARow= db.TableA.First(s => s.Id == 1); 
if (!tableARow.TableCs.IsLoaded) { tableARow.TableCs.Load(); }
```

or

```
var tableARow= db.TableA.Include("TableCs").First(s => s.Id == 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Puzzled, that looks more like it. Just one thing. With the s.Id == 1, it's actually the ID of tableC that I need to set to 1, not TableA. How would I do that? So it's a TableA entity i want to return, but i want to fill TableC having TableC.ID = 1 .... making sense?

Comment: A list of rows from table A which have rows from table C with Id = 1:

var tablearows = db.TableC.Include("TableAs").Where(c => c.Cid == 1).Select(c => c.TableAs).ToList();