# Entity Framework Join 3 Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to join three tables but I can't understand the method...

I completed join 2 tables

```
        var entryPoint = dbContext.tbl_EntryPoint
            .Join(dbContext.tbl_Entry,
                c => c.EID,
                cm => cm.EID,
                (c, cm) => new
                {
                    UID = cm.OwnerUID,
                    TID = cm.TID,
                    EID = c.EID,
                }).
            Where(a => a.UID == user.UID).Take(10);
```

[image: tables]

I would like to include **tbl_Title** table with **TID** PK and get **Title** field.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out this related article. It's not using the Method notation but, you should be able to get the gist...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204367/how-to-join-multiple-tables

Comment: Please show a picture with expanded navigation properties. Navigation properties are ready-made joins.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759590/joining-two-tables-in-entity-framework
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204367/how-to-join-multiple-tables

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This is untested, but I believe the syntax should work for a lambda query.  As you join more tables with this syntax you have to drill further down into the new objects to reach the values you want to manipulate.

```
var fullEntries = dbContext.tbl_EntryPoint
    .Join(
        dbContext.tbl_Entry,
        entryPoint => entryPoint.EID,
        entry => entry.EID,
        (entryPoint, entry) => new { entryPoint, entry }
    )
    .Join(
        dbContext.tbl_Title,
        combinedEntry => combinedEntry.entry.TID,
        title => title.TID,
        (combinedEntry, title) => new 
        {
            UID = combinedEntry.entry.OwnerUID,
            TID = combinedEntry.entry.TID,
            EID = combinedEntry.entryPoint.EID,
            Title = title.Title
        }
    )
    .Where(fullEntry => fullEntry.UID == user.UID)
    .Take(10);
```

Comment: @Dan Out of curiosity is it just the not thought out at all naming conventions with the c, cm, and ccm, or simply the syntax required to perform the joins using linq and lambda that is hideous? If the former, and you'd like to edit the post to have a better layout, by all means have at it.  I'm still new to entity framework and am still soaking in best practices so if you have suggestions to make this answer more eloquent for future users I'd appreciate the assistance.

Comment: I hadn't given the exact reason much thought when I commented, but certainly the naming conventions hurt readability (obv. copied from from OP). Also, the commas as the beginning of the line hurt readability a lot (subjective, for me), and whitespace / indentation could be slightly improved. I've submitted an edit with all of these (IMHO) improvements since you requested it.

Comment: Code formatting is often biased, but there are general things which most people agree look better. As for naming conventions, I used to call things really short names, but I can type plenty fast enough now (not even considering things like Intellisense) that the few characters saved is not worth the detriment in readability versus naming things verbosely e.g. "EntryID" vs. "EID", "combinedEntry" vs. "cm", etc. Eventually, someone else is going to read my code, and I'd rather they not grow hatred for me as a linear function of the number of lines of my code they've had to read / maintain.

Comment: I just don't get the arguments against commas starting lines. I'm a firm believer, as it makes commenting out individual clauses/arguments really easy. And it looks prettier :-)

Comment: Readability and semantics aside, this is a better answer than the usual `from x in context.table join ...` in my opinion. This way you can build your Joins and Where clauses dynamically and add paging and stuff later.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. A point to note if your query has includes then these must be placed before the joins.

Comment: @Auspex except it makes commenting out the first line harder ,just like putting the comma at the end makes commenting out the last line harder -so in the end there's no hardness difference .You're just left with trying to argue that starting a character sequence with punctuation looks prettier than ending a character sequence with punctuation ..Which as you can see ,from the punctuation in this comment ,is not true .

Answer (score 268):

I think it will be easier using syntax-based query:

```
var entryPoint = (from ep in dbContext.tbl_EntryPoint
                 join e in dbContext.tbl_Entry on ep.EID equals e.EID
                 join t in dbContext.tbl_Title on e.TID equals t.TID
                 where e.OwnerID == user.UID
                 select new {
                     UID = e.OwnerID,
                     TID = e.TID,
                     Title = t.Title,
                     EID = e.EID
                 }).Take(10);
```

And you should probably add `orderby` clause, to make sure `Top(10)` returns correct top ten items.

Comment: Thank you very much for the method; works clear but I would like to see the answer as I asked, thanks a lot again.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek : if i need a ViewModel to work , is  it  necessary that i join the tables?

Comment: This doesn't work even without async. I have the exact scenario but the query throws an exception [the_list_of_all_return_variables]' cannot be serialized . @marcinJuraszek - Could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453123/get-selected-values-after-joining-multiple-tables-in-entity-framework-6-using-la

Comment: I prefer the other syntax except when it comes to joins.... the other syntax is so much more convoluted. I don't get it at all.

Comment: The syntax-based query is more compact code and scales better when you have to join many tables. The benefit of lambda query is that it uses standard C# syntax while the syntax-based query uses special constructs.