# Get a value going through several tables in entity framework?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

I have a situation where I am trying to get a value stored in one table, but have to go through several other tables on the same database to get the correct result.

Table 1 has a PK ID I can query, this PK will give me a new FK in table 2, this will give me a key to table 3 and table 3 will give me key to table 4 that has the value stored against the PK in table 1. If this made sense? I can not do something with the tables or the database, so I need to find a way to select the value in table 4 from the primary key I got in table 1.

Any ideas?

Edit 1 :

I will try to explain better. I have a **filepath** located in table 4. To get the correct filepath I need to first find the a **project id** in table 1. That same **project id** is a FK in table 2. In table 2 I need to find another id (let's call it "**customer id**") using **project id** as FK, the **customer id** is a FK in table 3. In table 3 I need to find purchase id using **customer id** as FK, the **purchase id** is a FK in table 4. With the correct FK (**purchase id**) in table 4, I am able to get the correct **filepath**. The filepath that coresponds with the project id from table 1.

I am using ASP.NET (Entity Framework) and a SQL database. I was thinking to use Linq, but is somewhat confused about how to do it. Join several tables or try to get the filepath that way?

Did this make it more clear?

Comment: What's the question/problem? This is extremely vague.

Comment: ... and which RDBMS?

Comment: I tried to clear it up. See edit.

Comment: I was thinking to use Linq - that's good, but in what stage are you in that process? Evidently, we're not going to guide you through a beginner's course on EF here. If you're stuck on a piece of code, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

use Linq join Query,..

One example, See here 
[Entity Framework Join 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framwork-join-3-tables)

or search LINQ join in Google,you  can find the solution yourself.