# Calling a model within a model in a view. (asp.net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

Bare in mind, I'm quite new to ASP.NET MVC. So using EF code first method, I created 2 models, Movie and Producer:

```
public class Movie {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Genre {get;set;}
    public Producer Producer {get;set;}
}
public class Producer {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime DOB {get;set;}
    public List<Movie> Movies {get;set;}
}
```

And in the controller class "Movies", I called a view:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
//context just has DbSet< .. > of both classes.
MoviesContext db = new MoviesContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var movies = from m in db.Movies
                     select m;
        return View(movies.ToList());
    }
}
```

But if I call the producer within the view

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.Producer.Name</p>
}
```

MVC crashes with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error, even though when I look at the database, the Producer_ID field (which Code first made) was filled in and all of the producers with the according ID's exist in the database as well.

I did put the values inside the database manually, is that what would be causing it?

Any kind of help is more than appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try loading `Producer` data explicitly, by calling function `Include()`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var movies = from m in db.Movies.Include(b => b.Producer) 
                 select m;
    return View(movies.ToList());
}
```

If lazy loading is enabled, your property `Producer` would be loaded first time it is needed. However, if lazy loading is disabled, you need to explicitly specify that you want to load other related entities.

The method [`Include` that accepts a lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.include(v=vs.113).aspx) is an extension method, so you will need to add this using at the top of your file:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Alternative is to specify include by using string:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var movies = from m in db.Movies.Include("Producer") 
                 select m;
    return View(movies.ToList());
}
```

The result is the same, but first approach does not contain "magic strings", which is often preferable.

Comment: I can't accept the answer for another 4 minutes. It worked perfectly. I'd just note (for future viewers) that you need to include System.Data.Entity. Thank you very much for answering! :) I'd just like to ask, if I had another model (ex. public MainActor MainActor {get;set;} ), could I include both? (var movies = from m in db.Movies.Include(p => p.Producer).Include(ma => ma.MainActor))?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong, just put a break point before the return and check if the movies.Producer is not null, i beat yes..
You need to Include producer like this:

```
  var movies = from m in db.Movies.Include(m => m.Producer)
```

Or maybe do a join with Producer table, see a 3 table join example (in your case is just 2) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framwork-join-3-tables)