# Entity Framework add new propertie in existing list

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using this code in order to query through the database and inserting the values into a model:

```
  UserContext user = new UserContext();

 List<MitarbeiterDataModel> mitarbeiter = new List<MitarbeiterDataModel>();
 var users = user.Users.Select(x => new MitarbeiterDataModel{ Id = x.Id, Vorname = x.Vorname, Nachname = x.Nachname, Studio = x.Studio }).ToList();
 mitarbeiter.AddRange(users);
```

Now I have a list of employees which looks like this for example:

```
------------------------------
| Id | Name | Opportunities  |
------------------------------
| 1  | Tom  |                |
------------------------------
| 2  |John  |                |
------------------------------
```

My goal is to fill the Opportunities column as well. The problem is that these values are from another table. So I have to add them later somehow. Can someone tell me how to do this?

```
mitarbeiter.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => new MitarbeiterDataModel { Gelegenheiten = 2 });
```

'Gelegenheiten' means opportunities and is present in my dataModel which is `MitarbeiterDataModel` .
I tried it somehow this way... No success though:(

Comment: Why don't you join the tables? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables

Comment: Can I do this with assigning it to a propertie? The value of the second table hast to take the variable name of the viewmodel. Like it has to be something like this 'Gelegenheiten = 2'. It is important that the name is 'Gelegenheiten'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jeff Orris said, you can join both tables, then create your viewModels like so :

```
UserContext context = new UserContext();

List<MitarbeiterDataModel> mitarbeiter = new List<MitarbeiterDataModel>();

var users = (
    from user in context.Users
    join opp in context.Opportunities on user.OppurtunityId equals opp.OppurtunityId
    select new MitarbeiterDataModel { 
        Id = user.Id, 
        Vorname = user.Vorname, 
        Nachname = user.Nachname, 
        Studio = user.Studio,
        Gelegenheiten = opp.SomeField
        })
    .ToList();

mitarbeiter.AddRange(users);
```

Of course, i don't know the content of your classes, so I made up some fields.

Answer (score 0):

For the Legacy data I think you can use the SQL vernier to handle it, like

declare @Opportunitiesint

declare updatetrigger cursor for
select Opportunities from Gelegenheiten where ***

open updatetrigger
fetch next from updatetrigger into @Opportunities
while @@fetch_status=0
begin

```
update employees set Opportunities =@Opportunities where ***
```

fetch next from updatetrigger into @Opportunities 
end
deallocate updatetrigger