# Inner join Identity table with another table from different DB

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I want to get the `UserName` from identity and associate it to his Id as foreign key from another table. I know I have to do an inner join, but I don't really know how I can do this using Razor, hope someone can help me

**Code:**

```
var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();

ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users_Groups.Where(o => o.IdGroup == id), "IdUser", /*Username here */);
```

**DB:**
[image]

Comment: Could you please clear up what you want to join with what and what values you want to extract from the results? It is not really clear from your phrasing.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21051754/809357