# Entity Framework nested joins

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I am new to entity framework and am having a hard time trying to figure out how to query with a join when my models look like this (drastically simplified)

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public Vehicles Vehicles {get; set;}   
}

class Vehicles
{
    public List<Vehicle> Items {get; set;}
}

class Vehicle
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int CustomerId {get; set;}
}
```

If I put the `List<Vehicle>` on the customer class directly. I am able to do fluent mapping like this

```
builder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Items)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId);
```

Which then I can do this and I get back a customer object with vehicles

```
db.Customers.Include(x => x.Items).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

What I am not understanding is how to do this with my original set of models. I would like to keep them the way they are if possible. I have tried doing various versions of this in my `onModelCreating` method with no luck.

```
builder.Entity<Customer>(t =>
{
    t.OwnsOne(x => x.Vehicles, v =>
    {
        v.HasMany(x => x.Items).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId);
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you have an entity vehicles as a container for a list of vehicles? That does not sound clean. If that's what you BO's look like, you should consider converting them into model objects to save one table and the one-to-one relationship. Also, you may consider either exposing or hiding all FK properties to be consistent.

Comment: This is unusual model, so it's not surprising that it's problematic to be mapped. The way `Vehicles` class is defined in the example (w/o additional properties) it makes no sense. In order to try helping, we need to know the meaning of `Vehicles` class - is it an *entity* (and if yes, does it have its own table or has to be stored in the `Customer` table) or just a some sort of a container class?

Comment: It is a container class. It does not have its own table. The two tables involved in this are a customers table and a vehicles table. I'm attempting to reuse a large set of entities that exist in this solution. They aren't exactly representative of the database but are very close. I've been able to make the rest of it work with fluent mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to map the original classes, but in quite counterintuitive way.

Since the `Vehicles` class is just a container, mapping it as owned entity as you have tried seems the most natural way. However currently EF Core does not allow owned entity to be at the principal side of the relationship, and in your case this is needed.

So instead you need to map the `Vehicles` class as regular "entity" sharing the same table with the `Customer` - the so called [table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#table-splitting). You have to do explcitly all that EF Core does implicitly for owned entities - define a [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) and map is a both PK and FK for the one-to-one relationship with the `Customer`. You'd need also the explicitly map the `Vehicle.CustomerId` as a FK because from EF point of view the `Vehicle` is related to `Vehicles` rather than to `Custome`, hence the conventional FK property / column name assumed will be `VehiclesId`. Note that with this model you'll never be able to define an inverse navigation property `Customer` of the `Vehicle`.

With that being said, here is the fluent configuration needed:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicles>(builder =>
{
    // Table
    builder.ToTable(modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Metadata.Relational().TableName);
    // PK
    builder.Property<int>("Id");
    builder.HasKey("Id");
    // One-to-one relationship with Customer
    builder.HasOne<Customer>()
        .WithOne(e => e.Vehicles)
        .HasForeignKey<Vehicles>("Id");
    // One-to-many relationship with Vehicle
    builder.HasMany(e => e.Items)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.CustomerId);
});
```

and usage:

```
db.Customers
    .Include(x => x.Vehicles.Items) // <--
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Join`

See this question for some examples:

[Entity Framework Join 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables/21051754#21051754)