# Join 2 tables in report viewer in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I created report viewer in ASP.NET MVC, between 2 tables.

I created adapter to get all data in report like this :

[image]

But when I export report come like this, the `expence_type` does not show the data:

[image]

This is my code:

```
 public ActionResult Reports(string ReportType)
    {
        LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
        localreport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ExpenseReport.rdlc");



        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();

        reportDataSource.Name = "DataSetE";

        var dataList = (from ed in _context.ExpenseDetails
         join e in _context.Expenses on ed.ExpensesId equals e.Expenses_Id

     select new { id = ed.ExpenseDetails_Id, amount = ed.Amount, expense = ed.DateExpense, eid = ed.ExpensesId, expenseType = e.Expenses_Type }).ToList();

        reportDataSource.Value = dataList;


        reportDataSource.Value = _context.ExpenseDetails.ToList();

        localreport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        string reportType = ReportType;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        if (reportType == "Excel")
        {
            fileNameExtension = "xlsx";
        }

        if (reportType == "Word")
        {
            fileNameExtension = "docx";
        }

        if (reportType == "PDF")
        {
            fileNameExtension = "pdf";
        }

        else
        {
            fileNameExtension = "jpg";

        }

        string[] streams;
        Warning[] warnings;
        byte[] renderedByte;

        renderedByte = localreport.Render(reportType, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename = expens_report." + fileNameExtension);

        return File(renderedByte, fileNameExtension);
    }
```

Expense Details Models :

```
public class ExpenseDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int ExpenseDetails_Id { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateExpense { get; set; }

    public int ExpensesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExpensesId")]
    public virtual Expenses expenses { get; set; }
}
```

Expenses Models :

```
   public class Expenses
{
    [Key]
    public int Expenses_Id { get; set; }
    public string Expenses_Type { get; set; }
}
```

How can I show the `Expence_Type` ?

```
reportDataSource.Value = _context.ExpenseDetails.ToList();
```

I tried to add the other table in this code but it is not returned.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is there any relationship between two tables ?

Comment: Yes there are relationship between them

Comment: Can help me please , i want to create the report

Comment: can you pls post your table here or create join between two tables using entity framework and assign them  reportDataSource.Value check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables)

Comment: I update my Q and i add the model can you check ples

Comment: I see the link but i do not understand where i put that , can help me ? it is first project for me in mvc

Comment: Try this

var dataList = (from ed in _context.ExpenseDetails
                 join e in _context.Expenses on ed.ExpensesId equals e.Expenses_Id 
                 select new {
                     id = ed.ExpenseDetails_Id ,
                     amount = ed.Amount ,
                     expense = ed.DateExpense ,
                     eid = ed.ExpensesId ,
      expenseType = e.Expenses_Type 
                 }).ToList();

and add this 
reportDataSource.Value = dataList ;

Comment: Thank you; I but this in the same code of the report ?

Comment: i have updated code and you can add this before reportDataSource.Value and check that all value are coming

Comment: is this is working for you ?

Comment: I will try now , i hope it is work

Comment: it is not coming

Comment: what is not coming ?

Comment: I update the cord in the Q can check if i write the code correct

Comment: I mean the expense type it is empty when i export

Comment: so, it is giving data in report right ?

Comment: now another issue is expense type is empty ?

Comment: yes , can see the pic in my Q you see the expense type not have any data when i export

Comment: basically your question is resolved, there are some issue between your relationship

Comment: i have posted answer pls accept my answer so this will help to some one

Answer (score 0):

You can create join between two table and assign this as your report data source

Try this

```
var dataList = (from ed in _context.ExpenseDetails
                 join e in _context.Expenses on ed.ExpensesId equals e.Expenses_Id 
                 select new {
                     id = ed.ExpenseDetails_Id ,
                     amount = ed.Amount ,
                     expense = ed.DateExpense ,
                     eid = ed.ExpensesId ,
                     expenseType = e.Expenses_Type 
                 }).ToList();
```

and add this

```
reportDataSource.Value = dataList ;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191652/discussion-on-answer-by-mustufa-join-2-tables-in-report-viewer-in-asp-net-mvc).