# C# How to access fields tables in joint tables in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Supposing i have 3 tables in the below picture that joined together. how can i access 'Email' field in 'Users' table in my query on 'UserReferralJoins' table ?

can any one help me?

```
var referalId = await _dbContext.UserReferrals.Where(x => x.UserId == CurrentUserId).Select(x => x.UserReferralId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var list = await _dbContext.UserReferralJoins
            .Where(i => i.UserReferralId == referalId)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Id = x.UserReferralJoinId,
                UserEmail = ???
                x.JoinDate
            }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

[image]

Comment: Please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables . Should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The name of field in your table is very important
I see that your join field name is correct in your database as I see in picture
very simply you can use linq query for fetching your purpose
for example use
'userreferral'. user and fetch the field of user table.
if you want more help plz comment me.

Comment: i can't exactly what you say ? can you guide me more clear?!

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern in your select query

```
 UserEmail =x.UserReferral.ReferralCode
```