# EntityFramework query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework, linq

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    UserId int auto_increment,
    RegisterId int,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
    ProductId int auto_increment,
    ProductName varchar(10),
    UserId int,
    PRIMARY KEY(ProductId)
);
ALTER TABLE products 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_products_users_UserId
FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES users(UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO users values( 1, 3);
INSERT INTO products values (1, "Television", 1) ; 
INSERT INTO products values (2, "IPhone", 1) ;
INSERT INTO products values (3, "Television", 1) ;
```

```cs
using (var db = new someEntities())
{
   var dbReturn = db.users.Join(db.products,
                    x => x.UserId,
                    y => y.UserId,
                    (x, y) => new
                    {
                        x.RegisterId,
                        x.UserId,
                        y.ProductId,
                        y.ProductName
                    })
                    .Where(w => w.UserId == 1)
                    .GroupBy(g => g.RegisterId)
                    .Where(w => w.OrderByDescending(o => o.ProductId)
                          .FirstOrDefault()
                          .ProductName == "Television")
                    .Select(t => new
                    {
                        ProductId = t.Select(s => s.ProductId)
                                        .FirstOrDefault(),
                        ProductName = t.Select(s => s.ProductName)
                                        .FirstOrDefault(),
                        Key = t.Key,
                    })
                    .ToList();
   Console.WriteLine(dbReturn.FirstOrDefault().ProductId);
}
```

Unexpectedly, i get an error saying

> MySqlException: Unknown column 'Join1.RegisterId' in 'where clause'".

When i query (generated sql) in mysql than i get same error as expected.

There is no `AS JOIN1` in sql query.

So, what is wrong with my linq query?

```sql
SELECT 
1 AS `C1`,
CASE WHEN (`Project8`.`C1` IS NOT NULL) THEN (`Project8`.`C2`)  ELSE (0) END AS `C2`, 
`Project8`.`C3`, 
`Project8`.`RegisterId`
 FROM (SELECT 
`Project6`.`RegisterId`, 
`Project6`.`C1`, 
`Project6`.`C2`, 
(SELECT 
`Extent10`.`ProductName`
 FROM `users` AS `Extent9` INNER JOIN `products` AS `Extent10` ON `Extent9`.`UserId` = `Extent10`.`UserId`
 WHERE (1 = `Extent9`.`UserId`) AND ((`Project6`.`RegisterId` = `Extent9`.`RegisterId`) OR ((`Project6`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL) AND (`Extent9`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL))) LIMIT 1) AS `C3`
 FROM (SELECT 
`Project4`.`RegisterId`, 
`Project4`.`C1`, 
(SELECT 
`Extent8`.`ProductId`
 FROM `users` AS `Extent7` INNER JOIN `products` AS `Extent8` ON `Extent7`.`UserId` = `Extent8`.`UserId`
 WHERE (1 = `Extent7`.`UserId`) AND ((`Project4`.`RegisterId` = `Extent7`.`RegisterId`) OR ((`Project4`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL) AND (`Extent7`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL))) LIMIT 1) AS `C2`
 FROM (SELECT 
`Apply1`.`RegisterId`, 
(SELECT 
`Extent6`.`ProductId`
 FROM `users` AS `Extent5` INNER JOIN `products` AS `Extent6` ON `Extent5`.`UserId` = `Extent6`.`UserId`
 WHERE (1 = `Extent5`.`UserId`) AND ((`Apply1`.`RegisterId` = `Extent5`.`RegisterId`) OR ((`Apply1`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL) AND (`Extent5`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL))) LIMIT 1) AS `C1`
 FROM (SELECT 
`Distinct1`.`RegisterId`, 
(SELECT 
`Project2`.`ProductId`
 FROM (SELECT 
`Extent4`.`ProductId`, 
`Extent4`.`ProductName`
 FROM `users` AS `Extent3` INNER JOIN `products` AS `Extent4` ON `Extent3`.`UserId` = `Extent4`.`UserId`
 WHERE (1 = `Extent3`.`UserId`) AND ((`Join1`.`RegisterId` = `Extent3`.`RegisterId`) OR ((`Join1`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL) AND (`Extent3`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL)))) AS `Project2`
 ORDER BY 
`Project2`.`ProductId` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `ProductId`, 
(SELECT 
`Project2`.`ProductName`
 FROM (SELECT 
`Extent4`.`ProductId`, 
`Extent4`.`ProductName`
 FROM `users` AS `Extent3` INNER JOIN `products` AS `Extent4` ON `Extent3`.`UserId` = `Extent4`.`UserId`
 WHERE (1 = `Extent3`.`UserId`) AND ((`Join1`.`RegisterId` = `Extent3`.`RegisterId`) OR ((`Join1`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL) AND (`Extent3`.`RegisterId` IS  NULL)))) AS `Project2`
 ORDER BY 
`Project2`.`ProductId` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `ProductName`
 FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT 
`Extent1`.`RegisterId`
 FROM `users` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `products` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`UserId` = `Extent2`.`UserId`
 WHERE 1 = `Extent1`.`UserId`) AS `Distinct1`) AS `Apply1`
 WHERE @gp1 = `Apply1`.`ProductName`) AS `Project4`) AS `Project6`) AS `Project8`
```

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL?

Comment: i added generated Sql.

Comment: It looks like you are joining the `users` table to the `products` table and in the join criteria you have defined `RegisterId`... but the products table doesn't have a `RegisterId`. The `JOIN1` looks like pseudonym for the JOIN in the LINQ query... not in the actual SQL query. I'm not to strong on these LINQ queries to SQL though. Check out this post, it may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables

Comment: I think you have triggered a bug in EF (what version are you using). The SQL refers to `Join1` but does not include a definition for it.

Comment: i am using version 6.4.4...also i get same error with versions 6.4.0 and 6.3.0.

Comment: Why do you have the `ToList` in the middle of the LINQ query?

Comment: it is unnecessary, i am gonna delete it. thanks for warning.

Comment: Does that change the generated SQL?

Comment: nope. same error.